# Azure auto increment/Identity

Tags: javascript, database, azure, auto-increment

How do you make a column auto-increment in azure?

The only answers I have found relating to this are how you make columns auto-increment after the table has been created and pretty much every answer just says "you have to wipe the table before you can do it".... then doesn't actually say how you can do it.

I am using azure with js/html as my app if that makes a difference.  Also currently using the dynamic schema.  I cannot find a way to do it through azure because it seems to be a confusing interface.